# Given a frequency distribution, calculate probability of A given B

Tags: conditional-probability, frequentist, frequency

My test recorded the number of times a variable reached a threshold value when a predetermined event occurred. Then, the test recorded the number of times the variable surpassed the threshold value by 1 level when the same event occurred. The test progressed in this manner with the highest observation at level 22. The resulting frequency distribution follows (sample size was 9,970 observations):

- 0:3468 <= the threshold level
- 1:2163 <= level 1
- 2:1408
- 3:1005
- 4:641
- 5:487
- 6:266
- 7:196
- 8:135
- 9:71
- 10:49
- 11:30
- 12:16
- 13:6
- 14:10
- 15:8
- 16:3
- 17:4
- 18:0
- 19:1
- 20:1
- 21:1
- 22:1 <= level 22

Note that the frequency of Level 1 observations do not include the frequency of Level 0 (the threshold) observations. Finally, in order for the variable to reach subsequently higher levels, it must pass through lower levels.

During runtime, given that the variable has reached the threshold level(0), what's the probability that the variable will continue to level 1? to level 10?

Comment: Do you mean that the total number that reached level $l$ is actually the value recorded there, *plus* all the values listed for the levels above $l$?

Comment: That cannot be, see level 18.

Comment: @gung: if the variable moved through level 0, level 1, level 2 and then stopped at level 3, only the bin for level 3 would be incremented by 1 (not the bins for levels 0,1,2,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the formula for conditional probability is:
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
In your case, your $P(B)$ is the probability of breaching the threshold. There are $3468+2163+1408+1005+641+487+266+196+135+71+79+30+16+6+10+8+3+4+0+1+1+1+1 = 9968$ observations in the denominator. The probability of breaching level 1 is just the ratio of the observations that breached it given that they breached 0 or $\frac{6493}{9968} \approx 65.18\%$ and so on.

```
0   3468    9961    100.00%
1   2163    6493    65.18%
2   1408    4330    43.47%
3   1005    2922    29.33%
4   641 1917    19.25%
5   487 1276    12.81%
6   266 789 7.92%
7   196 523 5.25%
8   135 327 3.28%
9   71  192 1.93%
10  49  121 1.21%
11  30  72  0.72%
12  16  42  0.42%
13  6   26  0.26%
14  1   20  0.20%
15  8   19  0.19%
16  3   11  0.11%
17  4   8   0.08%
18  0   4   0.04%
19  1   4   0.04%
20  1   3   0.03%
21  1   2   0.02%
22  1   1   0.01%
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in this case, the numerator equals the number of observations beyond the threshold & the denominator equals the number of observations including the threshold. So, the probability of the test variable reaching level 2 given that it has already reached level 1 = 4430/6493 = 68.22%. Is this correct?

Comment: Your second sentence is correct, since $6493$ observations hit level $1$ and only $4330$ exceeded it. I'd state the first sentence as "the numerator is the number of observations at or above desired level (A) and the denominator is the number of observations at or above the "given" level (B)" when we want $P(A|B)$. The table is $P(\textrm{level} \ge n|\textrm{level} \ge 0)$, sorry about any confusion.